# How to make a SOAP call to WSUS Server

Tags: powershell, web-services, soap, wsdl, windows-update

How can I create an SOAP envelope to get update details from WSUS Server?

I found complete WSDL file and [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689723.aspx), when I tried hitting

```
10.66.195.242/ApiRemoting30/WebService.asmx
```

I'm getting Server error

> Server Error in '/ApiRemoting30' Application.
>
> Error: 2018-10-08 05:10:20 10.66.195.242 GET /ApiRemoting30/WebService.asmx - 80 NH-2K8-R2-3\administrator 10.44.141.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 500 0 0 5003

Comment: No one here is gonna write code for you. Can you give an example of what you've tried? We can help you that way.

Comment: When I tried hitting http://10.66.195.242/ApiRemoting30/WebService.asmx
I'm getting Server error
Server Error in '/ApiRemoting30' Application.

Error:
2018-10-08 05:10:20 10.66.195.242 GET /ApiRemoting30/WebService.asmx - 80 NH-2K8-R2-3\administrator 10.44.141.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:62.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/62.0 500 0 0 5003